# Descending Quicksort in Solidity

Tags: quicksort, solidity

I cannot find a descending quicksort for Solidity, this is my code based on this gist but is on ascending order: https://gist.github.com/subhodi/b3b86cc13ad2636420963e692a4d896f

```
function quickSort(uint[] memory arr, int left, int right) internal pure {
    int i = left;
    int j = right;
    if (i == j) return;
    uint pivot = arr[uint(left + (right - left) / 2)];
    while (i <= j) {
        while (arr[uint(i)] < pivot) i++;
        while (pivot < arr[uint(j)]) j--;
        if (i <= j) {
            (arr[uint(i)], arr[uint(j)]) = (arr[uint(j)], arr[uint(i)]);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    if (left < j)
        quickSort(arr, left, j);
    if (i < right)
        quickSort(arr, i, right);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was easier than I thought. Had to change only the comparing relating to pivot:

```
function quickSort(uint[] memory arr, int left, int right) internal pure {
    int i = left;
    int j = right;
    if (i == j) return;
    uint pivot = arr[uint(left + (right - left) / 2)];
    while (i <= j) {
        while (arr[uint(i)] > pivot) i++;
        while (pivot > arr[uint(j)]) j--;
        if (i <= j) {
            (arr[uint(i)], arr[uint(j)]) = (arr[uint(j)], arr[uint(i)]);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    if (left < j)
        quickSort(arr, left, j);
    if (i < right)
        quickSort(arr, i, right);
}
```

Comment: what's left and right?

Comment: @EightRice left and right indexes, but it's complicated to explain them in a comment. See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) for the quicksort algorithm to understand this in more detail.